# Formula to calculate adjusted score within range

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to come up with a formula to combine two different score types, where the second score will weight the first score without exceeding the upper or lower ranges of that score. In the interest of clarity, I'll call the first score a rank (0-3) and the second one I'll refer to as score (0-99).

A person can provide the rank for something, and then we're evaluating data to come up with what we think is the score based on historical activity, and we're using this calculated score to adjust a numerical representation of the rank. Since we have four ranks, we've assigned the following ranges:

```
Level    Range
0        00-24 (median 12)
1        25-49 (median 37)
2        50-74 (median 62)
3        75-99 (median 87)
```

So if someone ranks the item as a 1, we would start with a median score of 37. However, if the historical data shows a much higher score (let's say 95) then we want to adjust the number we'll be displaying within the range of the rank they selected (in this case it would be closer to 49). Likewise, if the historical data showed a score of 1 then it would skew their value down toward the lower boundary (of 25 in this example).

I could write a verbose function that would calculate what I'm looking for, but I was curious if there's a formula that could accomplish it, mostly because it's interesting to me but I'd need assistance to come up with it. If a formula is feasible, would it be possible to make it flexible so that the number of ranges could change (adjusting the median values, etc.)?

I'm looking for something that would know how to weight the score properly toward the upper or lower boundary of its range based on how far away the 2nd score is. I hope that is all clear enough.

Related question - what field of mathematics would this fall under? I couldn't even be sure what tag(s) to apply to this question! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully specified, but one way to do what you want is to take all the scores that have been given by users that assigned a specific rank, and then order those scores, and then, using quantiles (you can look up online), assign the scores to a new score that fits into the range for the particular rank and still respects the ordering of scores for users that gave that rank. For example, if your scores for rank 1 were 25 scores between 4 and 96 that made up all the multiples of 4 between 0 and 96, then you would divide each assigned score by 4 to get a representative new score between 0 and 24, such that the ordering of the scores was still maintained after making the transformation.